# how receive http post in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, request, http-post

send http post

```
import requests
payload =  [{'name': 'pippo', 'age':'7'}, {'name':'luca', 'age':'12'}]
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000", data=payload)
print(r.url)
```

Receive Http post in django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from home.models import Post


@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    all_post = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'request_method': request.method}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context['request_payload'] = request.POST.dict()
        post_data = dict(request.POST)
        print(post_data)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context['request_payload'] = request.GET.dict()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context, {'all_post':all_post})
```

in print(post_data) i not see [{'name': 'pippo', 'age':'7'}, {'name':'luca', 'age':'12'}]

why? where is my error?

Comment: What *do* you see?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `data` should be a dictionary, mapping the keys from the `request.POST` to a value, not a list...

Comment: in print(post_data)  is returning a what not I expected.

Comment: in print(post_data) I expected [{'name': 'pippo', 'age':'7'}, {'name':'luca', 'age':'12'}]

Comment: @Marco Can you post the result of **`print(post_data)`** ?

Comment: @JPG.. Yes i want should the result of print (post_data)....

Answer (score 0):

you should give a name to the data you want to post via requests. like this:

```
payload =  {'data': [{'name': 'pippo', 'age':'7'}, {'name':'luca', 'age':'12'}]}
```

and when you want to get data do it like this:

```
post_data = request.POST['data']
```